# Explain Like I'm 5 How Oath Spells Work (D&D 5e)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, paladin, spell-slots

What the title says. I genuinely cannot, for the life of me, figure out how they work. What spell slot would a level 8 Devotion Paladin use for Sanctuary? It says 3rd level, but I don't know if that's spell slot level or the level I would earn it at. (Level 8 Paladins do  not have slots above 2nd level) I lost my copy of the PHB, and all of the replies I have gotten have been rather esoteric for my tiny idiot brain. Please help if you can.

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205216/a-question-about-paladin-oath-spells is at least a highly-related question. Does it answer your question or are there aspects that you'd still like addressed?

Comment: @minnmass, since the questioner here is the same as the questioner there, I'm guessing that it didn't answer their question. Although I would recommend closing this as a dupe and seek more info from the original question.

Comment: @MivaScott: wow, totally misread the asker's name; good catch.

Comment: It should also be noted that you don't need the PHB for the Oath of Devotion Paladin. All the rules for them can be found in the SRD: [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#OathofDevotion) and [here](https://5e.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm).

Comment: @MivaScott [DnDBeyond - Paladin class](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin) is the best link, IMO

Answer (score 13):

You've misread something. Paladins do not receive "over leveled" spells. Sanctuary is a first level spell, received at paladin level 3. I recommend finding a PHB to confirm the information you've got.

## Oath Spells are Their Appropriate Level

#### Oath of Devotion Spells

| Paladin Level | Spells | Spell Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3rd | protection from evil and good, sanctuary | 1 |
| 5th | lesser restoration, zone of truth | 2 |
| 9th | beacon of hope, dispel magic | 3 |
| 13th | freedom of movement, guardian of faith | 4 |
| 17th | commune, flame strike | 5 |

The levels (other than paladin level 3) correlate to when paladins receive their next level of spell slots

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so, so much!

Comment: _I recommend finding a PHB_ For a moment I thought to myself "why would a pointy-haired boss know anything about paladins?"

Answer (score 7):

#### The level in the Oath Spells table is the Paladin class level you gain the spell.

Right before the oath spells table, we see this text:

> #### Oath Spells
>
> You gain oath spells at the paladin levels listed.
>
> ##### Oath of Devotion Spells
>
> | Paladin Level | Spells |
> | --- | --- |
> | 3rd | *protection from evil and good*, *sanctuary* |

So a Devotion Paladin gains the spell *sanctuary* upon reaching the 3rd Paladin class level. Since *sanctuary* is a 1st level spell, as noted in its spell description, you expend a 1st level spell slot to cast it.

Answer (score 7):

### You need to distinguish class level and spell level

The table of oath spells indicates at which **class level** the spell is obtained. Once you have it it works normally, *i.e.* it has the **spell level** indicated for that spell in the rule book. For example, *Sanctuary* is a first level spell, the level it is obtained at and your current level has no bearing on this. Of course you can cast spells at higher levels if this is useful for a given spell and you have the appropriate spell slots.